# define column names from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table

Table 1:

```
SELECT  
    "ColumnNm" ,
    "ColumnUserFriendlyNm"  
FROM table_1
```

which shows:

```
columnNm      ColumnUserFriendlyNm
key1          friendly name 1 
key2          friendly name 2
```

table 2 has column names "key1"  and "key2" and i want to change those column names to "friendly name 1 " and friendly name 2" according to the key in table 1

I need it to be automatically - so if i have 1000 columns like that i don't need to go 1 by 1 and manually write the alias in the code, I would like it to pull the "friendly name" according to the key from table_1

Answer (score 1):

Unless you create a `derived table` after aliasing the columns you have to `join` on the non-friendly names. In your `select` you can `alias` the columns that are returned in the final resulset:

**Example to `alias`**

```
SELECT  
    "ColumnNm" as [friendly name 1],
    "ColumnUserFriendlyNm" as [friendly name 2]  
FROM table_1
```

**Example to `alias` and use a derived table**

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT  
    "key1" as [friendly name 1],
    "key2" as [friendly name 2]  
FROM table_2 ) as table_2_aliasd
```

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-alias/

**If you need the `alias` to persist consider creating the the query using `alias` to a `view`**

```
create view dbo.vTable1_2
as
SELECT * from (
SELECT  
    "key1" as [friendly name 1],
    "key2" as [friendly name 2]  
FROM table_2 ) as table_2_aliasd
```

Comment: i need to be automatically - i have 100 columns like that i don't want to go 1 by 1 and manually write the alias in the code

Comment: @Manny you'll have to go one by one unless you write some dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Manny If you need all of the columns aliased, then the View with all the aliases is the better solution. Select only those you need from the view as needed. Better to get it all done once in once place than have to do it query by query.

Comment: @Adrian J. Moreno I also suggested that in the answer.

Comment: @vvvv4d Clarified my comment, just backing you up.

Answer (score 1):

The whole scenario could be like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
-- this is your test table
CREATE TABLE test (
  key01 INTEGER
, key02 INTEGER
, key03 INTEGER
, key04 INTEGER
, key05 INTEGER
, key06 INTEGER
, key07 INTEGER
, key08 INTEGER
, key09 INTEGER
, key10 INTEGER
)
;
CREATE TABLE mapname (
  column_name VARCHAR(32)
, user_friendly_column_name VARCHAR(32)
);
-- this is your name mapping table ...
INSERT INTO mapname
          SELECT 'key01' , 'friendly_name_01'
UNION ALL SELECT 'key02' , 'friendly_name_02'
UNION ALL SELECT 'key03' , 'friendly_name_03'
UNION ALL SELECT 'key04' , 'friendly_name_04'
UNION ALL SELECT 'key05' , 'friendly_name_05'
UNION ALL SELECT 'key06' , 'friendly_name_06'
UNION ALL SELECT 'key07' , 'friendly_name_07'
UNION ALL SELECT 'key08' , 'friendly_name_08'
UNION ALL SELECT 'key09' , 'friendly_name_09'
UNION ALL SELECT 'key10' , 'friendly_name_10'
;

SELECT
   'SELECT sp_rename '
+''''+table_name+'.'+c.column_name+''''
+' '''+user_friendly_column_name+''''
+' ''COLUMN'';'
FROM information_schema.columns c
JOIN mapname m ON m.column_name=c.column_name
WHERE table_schema='dbo'
  AND table_name='test'
;
```

-- and you get :

```
sp_rename 'test.key01' 'friendly_name_01' 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'test.key02' 'friendly_name_02' 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'test.key03' 'friendly_name_03' 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'test.key04' 'friendly_name_04' 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'test.key05' 'friendly_name_05' 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'test.key06' 'friendly_name_06' 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'test.key07' 'friendly_name_07' 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'test.key08' 'friendly_name_08' 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'test.key09' 'friendly_name_09' 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'test.key10' 'friendly_name_10' 'COLUMN';
```

Answer (score 0):

Manny, assuming you're trying to alias columns to a friendly name for a query vs. renaming physical columns, you will need to resort to dynamic SQL to do so.

Here's an example that might help you get started. Not knowing your data architecture, I took some liberty below. However, you should be able to modify this logic for what you need.

```
/* CREATE A MOCK-UP LIST OF TABLE OBJECTS */
DECLARE @Tables TABLE ( TableNm VARCHAR(50) );
INSERT INTO @Tables VALUES ( 'Table1' ), ( 'Table2' ), ( 'Table3' );

/* CREATE A MOCK-UP OF FRIENDLY NAMES THAT TIE BACK TO THE TABLE OBJECTS */
DECLARE @FriendlyNames TABLE ( TableNm VARCHAR(50), ColumnNm VARCHAR(50), ColumnUserFriendlyName VARCHAR(50) );
INSERT INTO @FriendlyNames ( TableNm, ColumnNm, ColumnUserFriendlyName ) VALUES
    ( 'Table1', 'key1', 'Friendly Name 1' ), ( 'Table1', 'key2', 'Friendly Name 2' );

-- Create a parameter of the table name to query.
DECLARE @TableQry VARCHAR(50) = 'Table1';

-- Create a dynamic sql statement of column/aliases for the requested table.
DECLARE @dynamic_sql AS VARCHAR(MAX) = (

    SELECT
        FORMATMESSAGE ( 'SELECT %s FROM %s;', FriendlyNames.Aliases, tbls.TableNm ) AS Dsql
    FROM @Tables AS tbls
    OUTER APPLY (
    
        SELECT
            STRING_AGG ( FORMATMESSAGE ( '[%s] AS [%s]', fn.ColumnNm, fn.ColumnUserFriendlyName ), ',' ) AS Aliases
        FROM @FriendlyNames AS fn
        INNER JOIN @Tables AS tbls
            ON fn.TableNm = tbls.TableNm
    
    ) AS FriendlyNames
    WHERE
        tbls.TableNm = @TableQry

);

-- Display the dynamic SQL created.
SELECT @dynamic_sql AS DynamicSql;
```

Returns

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                 DynamicSql                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT [key1] AS [Friendly Name 1],[key2] AS [Friendly Name 2] FROM Table1; |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Making no assumption of your SQL Server experience, to execute the dynamic SQL you can do the following:

```
-- Execute the dynamic sql.
EXEC ( @dynamic_sql );
```

You could expand your friendly names table to include a column order and more, but again, I'm making some assumptions about your need as it's not clear if your looking to actually rename a series of columns, or keep a list of friendly names that can later be used for querying.